# NGINX server_name not work

Tags: nginx

I ecountered the following issue about server_name in nginx and might need your help. This is my `default.cnf` resided in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  planner.dev;

    root   /var/www/planner.dev/src;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    ...
}
```

And I have a helloworld html file in `/var/www/planner.dev/src`
However, only `localhost` will run, `planner.dev` will not run.

```
$ curl planner.dev
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'planner.dev'
```

Comment: because planner.dev doesn't point anywhere. You need to e.g. put that domain name in your hosts file - this has nothing to do with nginx.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is most likely in the system hosting the server, than in the server itself.

I was running an Nginx server on Debian and happened to have the same issue, which I solved by editing the `/etc/hosts` file likeso:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       vacuum
127.0.0.1       <mywebsite>.localhost
```

More about the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is fixed by editing the hosts file of Centos, not relating to NGINX. Sorry everybody